ASP.NET Core 7 MVC - how to implement identity my project?
(sorry for my bad English)
I had previously created an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project and installed the dashboard. However, now I want to do authentication and authorization with the Microsoft.Identity library. Should I delete the User and Role entity classes that I have previously built?
Logging in as a user, changing the dashboard according to admin or staff.

What "Dashboard" do you mean? Also note that .NET 7 is out of support - you should really think about moving to 8.

it's a panel for my admin user. Admin use to crud transactions or will see the statistics.
